# I am trying get price of specific product using ajax call. so far i had tried this. but i am not getting the price after selecting product

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

my blade.php

```
<select name="productname[]" class="form-control productname">
   <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Product</option>
 @foreach ($stock as $product)
   <option value="{{$product->id}}">{{$product->productname}}</option>
 @endforeach
 </select>
```

user select product from here and i want ptice input feild auto-filled.

```
<td><input type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control price"></td>
```

using this javascript

```
 $('tbody').delegate('.productname','change', function(){
  var tr=$(this).parent().parent();
  var id = tr.find('.productname').val();
  var dataId={'id':id};
   $.ajax({
    type    :   'GET',
    url     : "{{route('findprice')}}",
    dataType:   'json',
    data    :   dataId,
    success:function(data){
        tr.find('text.price').val(data[0].price);
    }
   });
 });
```

and in my controller I am using this thing.

```
public function findprice(Request $request)
  {
   $data = Stock::where('price')->where('id',$request->id)->first();
   return response()->json($data);
  }
```

anyone who can help me out.

Comment: You didn't state the issue you're having, nor asked a question.

Comment: @Jeto update my question. thanks

Comment: Make sure you are getting selected product id in findPrice();

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in query. Add this

```
$data = Stock::select('price')
           ->where('id',$request->id)
           ->first();
```

You placed 'where' instead of 'select'